# dunglas/symfony-docker : Internal call to same project

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I've just tried https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/

But I can't ping my server Symfony itself. I'm trying to call my own API in the same project but the ping localhost from sf does not seem to work.

I've put a call.php and a receipt.php in public/, but I don't know what to do so that call.php ping receipt.php

I can access to https://localhost/call.php but call.php can't access https://localhost/receipt.php from my php script. I can access https://localhost/receipt.php from my navigator.

Comment: how are you calling the `receipt.php` from the `call.php` script?

Comment: actually, the caller is a soap client and the receilpt a server soap client. assuming the soapCLient is instanciated with the receipt addres, the $soap->AddressLookupUK(); failed, and say host not found (also all other server soap functions). i can access the server via boomerang (localhost/receipt.php)

Comment: a basic file_get_contents("localhost/receipt.php") failed too, from caller.php

Comment: what about `file_get_contents("receipt.php")`? I think you should drop the localhost from the path

Comment: You need to make the request to the service that runs the HTTP server. Caddy, in this case. So your request would be something like `curl http://caddy/receipt.php`.

Comment: well still don't work, with caddy/receipt.php.... but thanks for your answers. @PavelJanicek try a soap request pliz.